# Show that for $0<a, b<\infty$ $\int^\infty_0 \frac{\log(|\frac{\tan(bx)}{\tan(ax)}|)}{x}= +\infty \text{ if } b>0$...

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Show that for $0<a, b<\infty$ (This is not meaningless it is required for the equation with the $M(f)$ piece)
$$
  \int^\infty_0 \frac{\ln\Big(\Big|\frac{\tan(bx)}{\tan(ax)}\Big|\Big)}{x} = 
  \begin{cases}\begin{align}
    +\infty \quad&\text{ if }\; b>0, \\
    0 \quad&\text{ if }\; a=b>0, \\
    -\infty \quad&\text{ if }\; 0<b<a 
  \end{align}\end{cases}
$$

We can rewrite the original equation as: 
$$
  \int^\infty_0 \frac{\ln|(\tan(bx))|-\ln|(\tan(ax))|}{x}=
  \int^\infty_0 \frac{|f(bx)|-f|(ax)|}{x}=
  M(f)\ln(\frac{b}{a})
$$

$M(f):=lim \frac{1}{x} \int^x_0 f(t)dt$

So everything is going well until here. The problem is $M(f)=0$ for $\ln(\tan(x))$ which, as I hope you can see, is no good for us.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by $M(f)$?

Comment: Mean Value is I think what it stands for. That equation is in the book I'm using.

Comment: Okay. Well, firstly, $$\ln\left|\frac{\tan ax}{\tan bx}\right| \neq \ln\tan ax-\ln\tan bx $$

Comment: Should the first case be $b>a>0$ instead of $b>0$? (and in the first line, $a,b<\infty$ is meaningless)

Comment: @GregMartin It matters for the equation that I present at the end

Comment: @charlotte I've fixed it now.

Comment: @charlotte I also added the precise definition of M(f)